# Create account key for a user account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics

I know this is not an intended usecase but is it possible (potentially via some workaround) to create an authentication key (.json formatted) for a user account, the same way that you can for a service account? It seems to be the only way to authenticate a script for accessing both GCP and Google Analytics

Comment: GCP and Google analytics (Discovery services) don't use the same types of creational i dont think a service account created for one will work with the other.   But you can create service account json key file on both.  You would need to try.

Comment: Thats not what I'm asking. I want to know if it is possible to creade a json key file for a user account (i.e. non-service)

Comment: It depends. @guillaume's answer is correct in the context you asked. The exact answer depends on what type of user (Gmail or Workspace). Workspace supports user impersonation (Domain Wide Delegation) for service accounts. For Gmail, your request is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Service account are technical accounts that must be able to authenticate themselves, thus they have a secret key enclosed in the JSON.

For user account, you are able to authenticate yourselves with a login/password, and thus having a secret key is useless (in reality, it's dangerous!!)